# How to know bitmap size after reducing its size in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm loading the image from the url by using `LoadImage` method and storing it in the Bitmap object. Then I reduce its size. After getting the reduced image size I'm displaying it in the `ImageView` of my layout. Now I would like to know whether the image size was reduced or not. How can I check that?

```
public class ReduceImageActivity extends Activity {

    String image_URL = "http://pennapps.com/biblioteka/images/C.jpg";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView bmImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
        getResizedBitmap(bm, 200, 200);

        System.out.println("after resizing it"+bm);


        bmImage.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bm, 200, 200));
    }

    private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {

        int width = bm.getWidth();

        int height = bm.getHeight();

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // create a matrix for the manipulation

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        // resize the bit map

        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // recreate the new Bitmap

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, false);

        System.out.println("in getresizebitmap"+resizedBitmap.toString());



        return resizedBitmap;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getWidth`, `getHeight` as @barzos suggested. And keep in mind that call to `getResizedBitmap(bm, 200, 200)` does not change the original `bm` bitmap but rather produces a new one, so use it as following:

```
Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
Bitmap resized = getResizedBitmap(bm, 200, 200);

System.out.println("after resizing [w: " + resized.getWidth() + ", h: " + resized.getHeight() + "]");

bmImage.setImageBitmap(resized);
```

This also eliminates one unnecessary call to `getResizedBitmap` saving CPU and memory resources.

Comment: Its working fine it will not use CPU memory as you said the above will use CPU memory Thankyou verymuch .

Answer (score 2):

after you reduce image size, you can check size of new ( reduced ) image by using ;
`getWidth()
getHeight()`
use -> `resizedBitmap.getWidth(), resizedBitmap.getHeight()`